# updating spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb to a newer version

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter-parent

I'm working on an old version spring-boot-starter project.

I need to update the mongo driver to at least 3.11 (since moving to a new mongo host with a newer version). Because updating the whole project to a newer version of spring-boot-starter is not an option right now, I wanted to specifically update spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb. for that, I have found that I can do it by:

```
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Moore-SR7</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
```

that does the job, but the issue is that it is also updated the jpa driver version. Is there A way I can update updating spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb without updating spring-data-jpa.

Thanks a lot